# Gibberish Output in RPart plot in R

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I am trying to run a Decision Tree using `RPart` in R, on a data set with 26 variables to classify an outcome as 0 or 1. The model has a fair accuracy of 81% and when I go ahead and plot the tree, I get very gibberish variable splitting values. Ex: v10 contains a list of countries, say US, UK, India, etc. but the plot as shown here as some nonsensical values. v7 here was a list of URLs, v12 some quantitative numbers in my data set, but the tree values look screwed up.
[image: Decision Tree Using RPart]

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm replaces the levels of each factor by lower and upper case letters in the alphabet. If there are more than 56 levels in a factor, the Z letter is repeated, so it is not recommended to use factors with more than 56 levels as input to a rpart model.

However, it is possible to avoid the unwanted "gibberish" output: if you are using plot() + text(), try using the "pretty" parameter in the text() function.  Example:

```
plot(tree)
text(tree, pretty=1)
```

Other output functions have their specific parameter for that. "labels()" for instance, has the "minlength" parameter:

```
labels(tree)
labels(tree,minlength=0)
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that gave me the actual values at each node.